# jsonify append objects after creation

Tags: python, json, flask

I have a response created with jsonify and I need to add additional data in that response. Is this possible?

I have:

```
from flask import make_response, jsonify
resp = make_response(jsonify({"data": {"person": {"name": "ko", "error": "not responding"}}}), 500)
...
```

I need to do something like:

```
resp.append(jsonify({"value":1}))
```

So I can return both data and value in the same json.

Comment: Can't you just make 1 more complex JSON? I believe HTTP requests only allow 1 response...

Comment: Why don't you insert the value to the data dict before you make response?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest working with the data *before* making the response. Before `jsonify` is called on the data, it is simply a normal python dictionary object, and you can work with it as you please:

```
data = {"data": {"person": {"name": "ko", "error": "not responding"}}}

data['value'] = 1
# and any other processing here

make_response(jsonify(data), 500)
```

Edit: looking at the [flask Response object docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#response-objects) it doesn't look like it really wants you editing it once you have made the response. However if you really need to edit the response object after creating it, the flask docs here would be a good place to start.

Answer (score 1):

As it has already been said it's better not to modify the response object. Prepare the data, then `jsonify` it and return the response. However, you can still modify the response:

import json
from flask import make_response, jsonify

```
resp = make_response(jsonify({"data": {"person": {"name": "ko", "error": "not responding"}}}), 500)
data = json.loads(response.get_data())
# If you use python3 then add decode('utf-8') at the end.
# data = json.loads(response.get_data().decode('utf-8'))
data['value'] = 1
resp.set_data(json.dumps(data))
return resp
```